# CakePHP: How to detect an html event (like onChange) and call a specific controller

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0

I'm learning CakePHP, just began this week. 
So far I'm advancing good on retrieving and showing data from Tables and BelongToMany associations.

Now I'm stuck in a issue:
how to detect a specific field change of a form.

what I have:

```
 <?php foreach ($visit->contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
         // SOME CODE to display all contact info
       <td>
        // Show a description about the contact in the visit (like 
       //his comments, his opinions, etc), and allow to change 
       //anytime without to send to a Form page
         <?= $this->Form->create($contact->_joinData,[
         'url'=>['action' => 'updateDescription',$visit->id,$contact->id]]) 
        ?>

<?php
     echo $this->Form->control('description',['label'=>false, 
    'type'=>'textbox', 'onchange'=> $this->Form->submit()]);

    ?>

 </td> // AND MORE code; end foreach
```

In this page I want to detect a change in the description FORM send it to a specific controller update the table visit_contacts description column matching the visit_id and contact_id row.

The problem is how to detect the change, I want to detect and apply change when the user finishes the edit with an Enter or out focus, I used OnChange just to test the event but does not work.

I don't want to use a submit button.

How to detect an html event and call a specific controller

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use ajax for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that my code was right except for the call of the onChange funtion:

instead of having

```
'onchange'=> $this->Form->submit()]
```

it should be

```
'onchange'=> $this->Form->submit]
```

And so it submits to my controller when someone changes the text.

Hope this could help someone with the same issue